# Can't install dev-setup of hyperledger indy-node

Tags: python, python-3.x, hyperledger-indy

I am trying to install dev-setup on my  system using this link

> https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-node/blob/master/docs/source/setup-dev.md

as guide i followed all steps now while executing command `pip install -e .[tests]` I getting error: `failed to build wheels for leveldb, ujson, python-rocksdb, sha3, psutil, orderedset..`

I tried `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel` this command executes but then i am not able to run next command

```py
Building wheels for collected packages: leveldb, ujson, python-rocksdb, sha3, psutil, orderedset
  Building wheel for leveldb (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command /home/richa/test/bin/python3.5 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cwvzh10g/leveldb/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-ufgtvm7j --python-tag cp35:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
```

Comment: What version of Indy Node are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

Steps that are easy to miss in that guide include:

- Activating the virtual environment with `source activate`
- Installing wheel  with `pip install wheel`